# Triggering a Web page JavaScript function from a .Net application - separate process

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, function

Trying to determine if this is even possible first.

Have a need to be able to trigger a JavaScript function on a client webpage from our .Net application (WinForms - C#).

I.E. -> WebPage -> SomeJavascriptFunction

C# .Net application running in separate process -> call SomeJavascriptFunction

Obviously I can't call it directly, but I'm wondering if there are any tricks someone has come across in their endeavours.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is have the client's javascript code poll the server to see if there are any jobs. The WinForms application would insert a job into the database that a web service would read and present to the javascript AJAX call.

The javascript could poll the server every 15 seconds or so to see if there are any new jobs.

Comment: If using this approach, I'd probably implement something like SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are currently set up but at my work I have a Sever that a page listens to then invokes a java script object based on the results. Some of them are just a bool value, if it is set to true that it runs the script then sets the value back to false until the application runs again. I am guessing this is not ideally you wanted but as far as I am aware you will need to have that bridge between offline and online.

Hope this helps. If not sorry for wasting your time.

Roy